# Linux User generation script

Tags: linux, bash

Was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction.

I'm wanting to create a simple bash script to create user account.

The script will need to prompt the admin for a username and password for the new user. The user will need to be assigned to a group and their home directory needs to be changed to a standard default one that all users will use.

Any help would be great.

Thanks,
G

Comment: We generally don't write scripts for people but we are generally happy to help if you have a specific problem. This which I found via google might be a good place to start http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-write-shell-script-to-add-user.html.

Comment: Are you having some specific problem here?

Answer (score 2):

You're in luck! that "script" is already on your system)

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ useradd 
Usage: useradd [options] LOGIN

Options:
  -b, --base-dir BASE_DIR       base directory for the home directory of the
                                new account
  -c, --comment COMMENT         GECOS field of the new account
  -d, --home-dir HOME_DIR       home directory of the new account
  -D, --defaults                print or change default useradd configuration
  -e, --expiredate EXPIRE_DATE  expiration date of the new account
  -f, --inactive INACTIVE       password inactivity period of the new account
  -g, --gid GROUP               name or ID of the primary group of the new
                                account
  -G, --groups GROUPS           list of supplementary groups of the new
                                account
  -h, --help                    display this help message and exit
  -k, --skel SKEL_DIR           use this alternative skeleton directory
  -K, --key KEY=VALUE           override /etc/login.defs defaults
  -l, --no-log-init             do not add the user to the lastlog and
                                faillog databases
  -m, --create-home             create the user's home directory
  -M, --no-create-home          do not create the user's home directory
  -N, --no-user-group           do not create a group with the same name as
                                the user
  -o, --non-unique              allow to create users with duplicate
                                (non-unique) UID
  -p, --password PASSWORD       encrypted password of the new account
  -r, --system                  create a system account
  -s, --shell SHELL             login shell of the new account
  -u, --uid UID                 user ID of the new account
  -U, --user-group              create a group with the same name as the user
  -Z, --selinux-user SEUSER     use a specific SEUSER for the SELinux user mapping

[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$
```

Comment: The questioner doesn't say (s)he's on ubuntu.

Comment: @MadHatter What is `Ubuntu` has to do with anything??

Comment: RedHat and variants don't have `adduser`.

Comment: Actually OP didn't specified OS (`REDHAT` _OR_ `Ubuntu`) and I'm on `REDHAT` (that's where I copy and paste output of `adduser` command).

Comment: (1) I agree, which is why I thought a distro-specific answer that didn't spell out the limitation was a bit naff, and (2) that looks an *awful* lot like the output from `useradd --help`.  Is there any possibility that you're just using an alias?

Comment: @MadHatter in `RHEL` `adduser` is symlink to `useradd` (`/usr/sbin/adduser -> useradd`)

Comment: Oh, OK; I guess this answer is fair enough, then.  +1 from me!

Comment: This doesn't prompt for a username or password (encryped or not) or the home directory ...

Comment: @Iain that's true, my guess it'd be easier for `OP` to learn how to use `useradd` instead of scripting it, as in order to script you still need to learn how to use `useradd` first.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you create a script ? Configure correctely /etc/adduser.conf and use adduser...